# Odoo - Long process leads to XmlHttpRequestError BAD REQUEST error

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In odoo while I am doing any long process such as getting data from
amazon and process those data in odoo and after 5-10 min I am getting
this error don't know the reason why this happen.

```
XmlHttpRequestError BAD REQUEST
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
Invalid JSON data: ''
```

The process seems running in background in server but I am getting this error every time. This leads users into the wrong direction.

I am wondering why I am always getting this error? Is that a normal behavior ?

Even data processing will be done properly even after getting this
error, so I am not getting the meaning why this error pop out only in
long process.

Is there timeout issue happen with web server ?

Where I need to look out for that ?

> **UPDATE**
>
> I have did this process from different system and it seems everything
>   working fine over there.
>
> So what my guess is **"It is something related to browser end only"**
>
> May be browser is not able to manage such idle requests (may be any
>   request time out settings needs to be updated)

Comment: Hm i think that could be an interesting issue for [Odoo on github](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

It wasn’t clear at first but the tracing telling me exactly what the problem is **“cookie”**.

> **The problem was due to a cookie that has become corrupted**. Not sure
>   how it got that way but it seems that the last time it was generated
>   something went wrong.   The easy solution is to delete all your
>   cookies of that particular domain or should do this from private
>   window (incognito mode).